# How to use the date and time that i get from time.h function

Tags: c, time, using, time.h

Let's say the user is prompted for the date - e.g. *Friday*.
How can that string be used to correctly compare with another sting?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{

time_t current_time;
struct tm * time_info;
char timeString[9];
time(&current_time);
time_info = localtime(&current_time);

strftime(timeString, sizeof(timeString), "%A", time_info);
printf("%s\n",timeString);

if (timeString == "Friday")
    {printf("Weekday");

    }
else 
    {printf("not weekday");
    }


return 0;
}
```

The program keeps printing out *not weekday*.

Comment: If you want people to help you, you may want to look into [properly formatting C code](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [strncmp()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp) instead of comparing the string with `==`:

```
if (strncmp(timeString,"Friday",7) == 0)
    {printf("Weekday");

}
```

See this in action at tutorialspoint.com:
[Friday](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMMW80dl9XN1cySFU)

Currently, it is Thursday (for ~50% of the world) - so try this one:
[Thursday](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMZzBQRVpNWDVoTUE)